# Can I bind an array to an IN() condition in a PDO query?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, prepared-statement, where-in

I'm curious to know if it's possible to bind an array of values to a placeholder using PDO.  The use case here is attempting to pass an array of values for use with an `IN()` condition.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<?php
$ids=array(1,2,3,7,8,9);
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM table
     WHERE id IN(:an_array)'
);
$stmt->bindParam('an_array',$ids);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

And have PDO bind and quote all the values in the array.

At the moment I'm doing:

```
<?php
$ids = array(1,2,3,7,8,9);
$db = new PDO(...);
foreach($ids as &$val)
    $val=$db->quote($val); //iterate through array and quote
$in = implode(',',$ids); //create comma separated list
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM table
     WHERE id IN('.$in.')'
);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Which certainly does the job, but just wondering if there's a built in solution I'm missing?

Comment: [A complete guide on binding an array to an IN() condition](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in),
 including the case when you have other placeholders in the query

Comment: Question was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767530/php-using-pdo-with-in-clause-array). I reversed the duplicate flag because this question is 4 years older, has 4 times the views, 3 times the number of answers, and 12 times the score. It is clearly the superior target.

Comment: Anyone looking at this in 2020: You could try https://github.com/morris/dop for that.

Comment: @miken32 you should have made the *answer* as useful then. I've got a strange idea that answers on this here Q&A site are intended to help people, not to count the age or number of views.

Answer (score 303):

You'll have to construct the list of placeholders manually, adding a placeholder for each array member.

```
<?php
$ids     = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9];
$inQuery = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?'; // gets ?,?,?,?,?,?

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN($inQuery)");
$stmt->execute($ids);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Given `$inQuery` doesn't take any input and fully constructed from constant values (`?,` parts), it's safe to add such a variable in the query.

In case there are other placeholders in the query, you could use `array_merge()` function to join all the variables into a single array, adding your other variables in the form of arrays, in the order they appear in your query:

```
$arr = [1,2,3];
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo=? AND column IN ($in) AND bar=? AND baz=?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$params = array_merge([$foo], $arr, [$bar, $baz]);
$stmt->execute($params);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

In case you are using named placeholders, the code would be a little more complex, as you have to create a sequence of the named placeholders, e.g. `:id0,:id1,:id2`. So the code would be:

```
// other parameters that are going into query
$params = ["foo" => "foo", "bar" => "bar"];

$ids = [1,2,3];
$in = "";
$i = 0; // we are using an external counter 
        // because the actual array keys could be dangerous
foreach ($ids as $item)
{
    $key = ":id".$i++;
    $in .= ($in ? "," : "") . $key; // :id0,:id1,:id2
    $in_params[$key] = $item; // collecting values into a key-value array
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo=:foo AND id IN ($in) AND bar=:bar";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_merge($params, $in_params)); // just merge two arrays
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Luckily, for the named placeholders we don't have to follow the strict order, so we can merge our arrays in any order.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, and while I prefer it to iterating over the ids and calling PDO::quote(), I think the index of the '?' placeholders is going to get messed up if any other placeholders occure elsewhere in the query first, right?

Comment: yes, that would be a problem. but in this case you could create named parameters instead of ?'s.

Comment: In your second line of that code, there's a mismatched ")".  The ) after the 1 should be at the end.  Thanks though - very useful! :-)

Comment: Old question, but worth noting I believe, is that the `$foreach` and `bindValue()` is not required - just execute with the array. E.g: `$stmt->execute($ids);`

Comment: you might also want to check that the IDs in the array have the right type if they come from a request parameter. Using something like `is_numeric($id)` in the foreach.

Comment: Generating the placeholders should be done like this `str_repeat('?,', count($array) - 1). '?';`

Comment: +1 but as a suggestion: `$stmt->execute(array_values($ids))` because if you used positional parameters but `$ids` is an associative array it will break.

Comment: Just a tip for those unaware, you cannot mix named and unnamed parameters.  Therefore if you use named parameters in your query, switch them out to ?'s and then augment your bindValue index offset to match the position of the IN ?'s with wherever they are relative to your other ? params.

Comment: One issue to using `IN` in this manner is you that must know how many values there are when preparing the query.  This means you must prepare another statement anytime the number of array values change.

Comment: @fyrye: this is true, but honestly, i've rarely got to reuse prepared statements during a single page generation cycle - i mostly use them for security reasons, not necessarily performance (i'm not sure if prep statements make a difference outside of long running applications). you could always use an array for caching them.

Comment: @stefs I use it in this manner as well, providing the comment as a warning to those expecting for it to work when they change the number of values. Such as in complex object models. I also recommend your suggestion of storing the statements in an array as a workaround to the issue.

Comment: If I need to insert two different comma seperated strings into two different IN statments in the sql, how do I do it then?

Comment: I had a variable `$varID = '1, 2, 3, 4';` but it didn't work when I set `$ids = array($varID);`

I used instead `$ids = explode(',', $varID);` and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What if i have two in clauses?

Comment: @EslamSamehAhmed same principle applies. construct both inQueries and array-append the ids.

Comment: When executing with an array of numeric IDs, "[a]ll values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR" ([PDOStatement::execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)) and msql has to cast them as integers.

Comment: sorry for PDO. it does not support array values. i think they have to update it.

Comment: Your answer may work, but it's not any more of an in-built solution than Andru's, and both are hilariously overly-complicated because of PDO/Symfony/Doctrine never programmed an easy way to pass an array of values to a WHERE IN... I'm just miffed at how much custom code I have to make for this, I'm now sending one of these solutions to a function, which will probably end up as a custom class somewhere, which may end up as a public library, but probably this is already fixed in newer versions, I don't know, I'm still stuck on old versions, that's why I'm here.

Answer (score 193):

For something quick:

```
//$db = new PDO(...);
//$ids = array(...);

$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id IN ($qMarks)");
$sth->execute($ids);
```

Comment: Excellent, I had not thought to use the input_parameters argument in this way. 

For those whose queries have more parameters than the IN list, you can use array_unshift and array_push to add the necessary arguments to the front and end of the array.

Also, I prefer 
`$input_list = substr(str_repeat(',?', count($ids)), 1);`

Comment: You could also try `str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?'`. One less function call.

Comment: I used this with an array_diff to get an array which I wanted removed and it gave me an error, cause the 1st array element did not have the index value 0, therefore I had to use `array_values` on it first in order to reset the keys.

Comment: Not show sure about the security of this one.  It will work, but kind of defeats the purpose of prepared statements and looks vulnerable to injection, to me.

Comment: @erfling, this is a prepared statement, where's the injection going to come from?  I'll be more than happy to make any corrections if you can you back that up with some actual proof of that.

Comment: Preparing the statement doesn't prevent injection.  You have to bind the params.  If one of the indices of $ids where DROP table users;, it might very well be executed.  The most upvoted answer prevents this by looping and binding.

Comment: @erfling, yes, that is correct, and binding the params is exactly what we are doing in this example by sending `execute` an array of ids

Comment: Oh indeed.  Somehow missed the fact that you were passing the array.  This does indeed appear to be safe and a good answer. My apologies.

Comment: Why `count ($variables) - 1) . '?';` Why not just `count($variable)`

Comment: @RobertRocha because he appends `'?'` at the end (without the comma). Without the `-1` it would be something like `... IN (?,?,?,?,?,)` which is syntactically incorrect

Comment: What's about multiple `WHERE` statements? Like `"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = ? AND id IN ($qMarks)"`? `execute(array($name, $ids))` doesn't seem to work at all....

Comment: @Miguel, that's not correct, this is what's called using prepared statements to ensure type safety and prevent sql injection.  Check out how `PDOStatement::execute` works [here in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.execute.php)

Answer (score 47):

Is it so important to use `IN` statement? Try to use `FIND_IN_SET` op.

For example, there is a query in PDO like that

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, :array)
```

Then you only need to bind an array of values, imploded with comma, like this one

```
$ids_string = implode(',', $array_of_smth); // WITHOUT WHITESPACES BEFORE AND AFTER THE COMMA
$stmt->bindParam('array', $ids_string);
```

and it's done.

UPD: As some people pointed out in comments to this answer, there are some issues which should be stated explciitly.

1. `FIND_IN_SET` doesn't use index in a table, and it is still not implemented yet - see [this record in the MYSQL bug tracker](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37564). Thanks to @BillKarwin for the notice.
2. You can't use a string with comma inside as a value of the array for search. It is impossible to parse such string in the right way after `implode` since you use comma symbol as a separator. Thanks to @VaL for the note.

In fine, if you are not heavily dependent on indexes and do not use strings with comma for search, my solution will be much easier, simpler, and faster than solutions listed above.

Comment: IN() can use an index, and counts as a range scan.  FIND_IN_SET() can't use an index.

Comment: That's a point. I didn't know this. But any way there is no any requirements for performance in the question. For not so big tables it's much more better and cleaner than separate class for generating query with different numbers of placeholders.

Comment: Yes, but who has a not-so-big table these days?  ;-)

Comment: Another problem with this approach that what if there will be string with comma inside? For example`... FIND_IN_SET(description,'simple,search')` will work, but `FIND_IN_SET(description,'first value,text, with coma inside')` will fail. So the function will search  `"first value", "text", "with coma inside" `instead of desired `"first value", "text, with coma inside"`

Answer (score 43):

Since I do a lot of dynamic queries, this is a super simple helper function I made.

```
public static function bindParamArray($prefix, $values, &$bindArray)
{
    $str = "";
    foreach($values as $index => $value){
        $str .= ":".$prefix.$index.",";
        $bindArray[$prefix.$index] = $value;
    }
    return rtrim($str,",");     
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$bindString = helper::bindParamArray("id", $_GET['ids'], $bindArray);
$userConditions .= " AND users.id IN($bindString)";
```

Returns a string `:id1,:id2,:id3` and also updates your `$bindArray` of bindings that you will need when it's time to run your query. Easy!

Comment: This is a much better solution, since it does not break the binding of parameters rule. This is much safer than having inline sql as proposed by some others here.

Comment: Clean solution.

Answer (score 21):

very clean way for postgres is using the postgres-array ("{}"):

```
$ids = array(1,4,7,9,45);
$param = "{".implode(', ',$ids)."}";
$cmd = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ANY (?)");
$result = $cmd->execute(array($param));
```

Comment: it block sql injection?

Comment: @FábioZangirolami it is PDO, so yes.

Comment: To be clear, PDO doesn't guarantee safety.  Using prepared statements properly is what will provide protection from injection attacks.  (prepared statements in mysqli or pdo)

Answer (score 17):

Solution from EvilRygy didn't worked for me. In Postgres you can do another workaround:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,7,8,9);
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM table
     WHERE id = ANY (string_to_array(:an_array, ','))'
);
$stmt->bindParam(':an_array', implode(',', $ids));
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: This doesn't work: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text`. At least you need to add explicit casting.

Answer (score 16):

Here is my solution:

```
$total_items = count($array_of_items);
$question_marks = array_fill(0, $total_items, '?');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN (' . implode(',', $question_marks ). ')';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_values($array_of_items));
```

Note the use of array_values.  This can fix key ordering issues.

I was merging arrays of ids and then removing duplicate items.  I had something like:

```
$ids = array(0 => 23, 1 => 47, 3 => 17);
```

And that was failing.

Comment: Note: Using your solution, you can add items to the front or back of the array, so you can include other bindings.  
  
`$original_array`    
    
Add items before the original array:    
`array_unshift($original_array, new_unrelated_item);`    
Add items after the original array:    
`array_push($original_array, new_unrelated_item);`  
  
When the values are bound, the new_unrelated items will be placed in the correct locations.  This allows you to mix Array and non-array items.
`

Answer (score 12):

Looking at  [PDO :Predefined Constants](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) there is no PDO::PARAM_ARRAY which you would need as is listed on [PDOStatement->bindParam](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

> bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, **int $data_type** [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )

So I don't think it is achievable.

Answer (score 12):

I extended PDO to do something similar to what stefs suggests, and it was easier for me in the long run:

```
class Array_Capable_PDO extends PDO {
    /**
     * Both prepare a statement and bind array values to it
     * @param string $statement mysql query with colon-prefixed tokens
     * @param array $arrays associatve array with string tokens as keys and integer-indexed data arrays as values 
     * @param array $driver_options see php documention
     * @return PDOStatement with given array values already bound 
     */
    public function prepare_with_arrays($statement, array $arrays, $driver_options = array()) {

        $replace_strings = array();
        $x = 0;
        foreach($arrays as $token => $data) {
            // just for testing...
            //// tokens should be legit
            //assert('is_string($token)');
            //assert('$token !== ""');
            //// a given token shouldn't appear more than once in the query
            //assert('substr_count($statement, $token) === 1');
            //// there should be an array of values for each token
            //assert('is_array($data)');
            //// empty data arrays aren't okay, they're a SQL syntax error
            //assert('count($data) > 0');

            // replace array tokens with a list of value tokens
            $replace_string_pieces = array();
            foreach($data as $y => $value) {
                //// the data arrays have to be integer-indexed
                //assert('is_int($y)');
                $replace_string_pieces[] = ":{$x}_{$y}";
            }
            $replace_strings[] = '('.implode(', ', $replace_string_pieces).')';
            $x++;
        }
        $statement = str_replace(array_keys($arrays), $replace_strings, $statement);
        $prepared_statement = $this->prepare($statement, $driver_options);

        // bind values to the value tokens
        $x = 0;
        foreach($arrays as $token => $data) {
            foreach($data as $y => $value) {
                $prepared_statement->bindValue(":{$x}_{$y}", $value);
            }
            $x++;
        }

        return $prepared_statement;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
$db_link = new Array_Capable_PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

$query = '
    SELECT     *
    FROM       test
    WHERE      field1 IN :array1
     OR        field2 IN :array2
     OR        field3 = :value
';

$pdo_query = $db_link->prepare_with_arrays(
    $query,
    array(
        ':array1' => array(1,2,3),
        ':array2' => array(7,8,9)
    )
);

$pdo_query->bindValue(':value', '10');

$pdo_query->execute();
```

Answer (score 12):

When you have other parameter, you may do like this:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,7,8,9);
$db = new PDO(...);
$query = 'SELECT *
            FROM table
           WHERE X = :x
             AND id IN(';
$comma = '';
for($i=0; $i<count($ids); $i++){
  $query .= $comma.':p'.$i;       // :p0, :p1, ...
  $comma = ',';
}
$query .= ')';

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':x', 123);  // some value
for($i=0; $i<count($ids); $i++){
  $stmt->bindValue(':p'.$i, $ids[$i]);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 12):

For me the sexier solution is to construct a dynamic associative array & use it

```
// A dirty array sent by user
$dirtyArray = ['Cecile', 'Gilles', 'Andre', 'Claude'];

// we construct an associative array like this
// [ ':name_0' => 'Cecile', ... , ':name_3' => 'Claude' ]
$params = array_combine(
    array_map(
        // construct param name according to array index
        function ($v) {return ":name_{$v}";},
        // get values of users
        array_keys($dirtyArray)
    ),
    $dirtyArray
);

// construct the query like `.. WHERE name IN ( :name_1, .. , :name_3 )`
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name IN( " . implode(",", array_keys($params)) . " )";
// here we go
$stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 9):

I had a unique problem where, while converting the soon-to-be deprecated MySQL driver to the PDO driver I had to make a function which could build, dynamically, both normal parameters and INs from the same parameter array. So I quickly built this:

```
/**
 * mysql::pdo_query('SELECT * FROM TBL_WHOOP WHERE type_of_whoop IN :param AND siz_of_whoop = :size', array(':param' => array(1,2,3), ':size' => 3))
 *
 * @param $query
 * @param $params
 */
function pdo_query($query, $params = array()){

    if(!$query)
        trigger_error('Could not query nothing');

    // Lets get our IN fields first
    $in_fields = array();
    foreach($params as $field => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            for($i=0,$size=sizeof($value);$i<$size;$i++)
                $in_array[] = $field.$i;

            $query = str_replace($field, "(".implode(',', $in_array).")", $query); // Lets replace the position in the query string with the full version
            $in_fields[$field] = $value; // Lets add this field to an array for use later
            unset($params[$field]); // Lets unset so we don't bind the param later down the line
        }
    }

    $query_obj = $this->pdo_link->prepare($query);
    $query_obj->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Now lets bind normal params.
    foreach($params as $field => $value) $query_obj->bindValue($field, $value);

    // Now lets bind the IN params
    foreach($in_fields as $field => $value){
        for($i=0,$size=sizeof($value);$i<$size;$i++)
            $query_obj->bindValue($field.$i, $value[$i]); // Both the named param index and this index are based off the array index which has not changed...hopefully
    }

    $query_obj->execute();

    if($query_obj->rowCount() <= 0)
        return null;

    return $query_obj;
}
```

It is still untested however the logic seems to be there.

After some testing, I found out:

- PDO does not like '.' in their names (which is kinda stupid if you ask me)
- bindParam is the wrong function, bindValue is the right function.

Answer (score 8):

A little editing about the code of Schnalle

```
<?php
$ids     = array(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9);
$inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

$db   = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM table
     WHERE id IN(' . $inQuery . ')'
);

foreach ($ids as $k => $id)
    $stmt->bindValue(($k+1), $id);

$stmt->execute();
?>

//implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids)-1), '?')); 
//'?' this should be inside the array_fill
//$stmt->bindValue(($k+1), $in); 
// instead of $in, it should be $id
```

Comment: I had to remove -1 after count($ids) for it to work for me or there would always be  one placeholder missing.

Answer (score 7):

If the column can only contain integers, you could probably do this without placeholders and just put the ids in the query directly. You just have to cast all the values of the array to integers. Like this:

```
$listOfIds = implode(',',array_map('intval', $ids));
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    "SELECT *
     FROM table
     WHERE id IN($listOfIds)"
);
$stmt->execute();
```

This shouldn't be vulnerable to any SQL injection.

Answer (score 6):

What database are you using? In PostgreSQL I like using ANY(array). So to reuse your example:

```
<?php
$ids=array(1,2,3,7,8,9);
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM table
     WHERE id = ANY (:an_array)'
);
$stmt->bindParam('an_array',$ids);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Unfortunately this is pretty non-portable.

On other databases you'll need to make up your own magic as others have been mentioning. You'll want to put that logic into a class/function to make it reusable throughout your program of course. Take a look at the comments on `mysql_query` page on PHP.NET for some more thoughts on the subject and examples of this scenario.

Comment: Wonder if you ever learned that it would never work.

Answer (score 5):

As I know there is no any possibility to bind an array into PDO statement.

But exists 2 common solutions:

1. Use Positional Placeholders (?,?,?,?) or Named Placeholders (:id1, :id2, :id3)

   $whereIn = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
2. Quote array earlier

   $whereIn = array_map(array($db, 'quote'), $ids);

Both options are good and safe. 
I prefer second one because it's shorter and I can var_dump parameters if I need it.
Using placeholders you must bind values and in the end your SQL code will be the same.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($whereIn)";
```

And the last and important for me is avoiding error "number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Doctrine it's great example of using positional placeholders, only because it has internal control over incoming parameters.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to use an array like that in PDO.

You need to build a string with a parameter (or use ?) for each value, for instance:

`:an_array_0, :an_array_1, :an_array_2, :an_array_3, :an_array_4, :an_array_5`

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$ids = array(1,2,3,7,8,9);
$sqlAnArray = join(
    ', ',
    array_map(
        function($index) {
            return ":an_array_$index";
        },
        array_keys($ids)
    )
);
$db = new PDO(
    'mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost',
    'user',
    'passwd'
);
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM table
     WHERE id IN('.$sqlAnArray.')'
);
foreach ($ids as $index => $id) {
    $stmt->bindValue("an_array_$index", $id);
}
```

If you want to keep using `bindParam`, you may do this instead:

```
foreach ($ids as $index => $id) {
    $stmt->bindParam("an_array_$index", $ids[$id]);
}
```

If you want to use `?` placeholders, you may do it like this:

```
<?php
$ids = array(1,2,3,7,8,9);
$sqlAnArray = '?' . str_repeat(', ?', count($ids)-1);
$db = new PDO(
    'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost',
    'user',
    'passwd'
);
$stmt = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM phone_number_lookup
     WHERE country_code IN('.$sqlAnArray.')'
);
$stmt->execute($ids);
```

If you don't know if `$ids` is empty, you should test it and handle that case accordingly (return an empty array, or return a Null Object, or throw an exception, ...).

Answer (score 3):

After going through the same problem, i went to a simpler solution (although still not as elegant as an `PDO::PARAM_ARRAY` would be) :

given the array `$ids = array(2, 4, 32)`:

```
$newparams = array();
foreach ($ids as $n => $val){ $newparams[] = ":id_$n"; }

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM $table WHERE ($table.id IN (" . implode(", ",$newparams). "))");
    foreach ($ids as $n => $val){
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_$n", intval($val), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
```

... and so on

So if you are using a mixed values array, you will need more code to test your values before assigning the type param:

```
// inside second foreach..

$valuevar = (is_float($val) ? floatval($val) : is_int($val) ? intval($val) :  is_string($val) ? strval($val) : $val );
$stmt->bindParam(":id_$n", $valuevar, (is_int($val) ? PDO::PARAM_INT :  is_string($val) ? PDO::PARAM_STR : NULL ));
```

But i have not tested this one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, based on [alan_mm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition-in-a-pdo-query/15821138#15821138). I have also extended the PDO class:

```
class Db extends PDO
{

    /**
     * SELECT ... WHERE fieldName IN (:paramName) workaround
     *
     * @param array  $array
     * @param string $prefix
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function CreateArrayBindParamNames(array $array, $prefix = 'id_')
    {
        $newparams = [];
        foreach ($array as $n => $val)
        {
            $newparams[] = ":".$prefix.$n;
        }
        return implode(", ", $newparams);
    }

    /**
     * Bind every array element to the proper named parameter
     *
     * @param PDOStatement $stmt
     * @param array        $array
     * @param string       $prefix
     */
    public function BindArrayParam(PDOStatement &$stmt, array $array, $prefix = 'id_')
    {
        foreach($array as $n => $val)
        {
            $val = intval($val);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$prefix.$n, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a sample usage for the above code:

```
$idList = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$stmt = $this -> db -> prepare("
  SELECT
    `Name`
  FROM
    `User`
  WHERE
    (`ID` IN (".$this -> db -> CreateArrayBindParamNames($idList)."))");
$this -> db -> BindArrayParam($stmt, $idList);
$stmt -> execute();
foreach($stmt as $row)
{
    echo $row['Name'];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is getOne(), it doesn't seem to be part of PDO. I've seen it only in PEAR. What does it do exactly?

Comment: I would suggest passing the data type to `BindArrayParam` in the associative array as you seem to be limiting this to integers.

Answer (score 2):

With MySQL and PDO we can use a JSON array and `JSON_CONTAINS()` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) to search in.

```
$ids = [123, 234, 345, 456]; // Array of users I search
$ids = json_encode($ids); // JSON conversion

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT ALL user_id, user_login
    FROM users
    -- Cast is mandatory beaucause JSON_CONTAINS() waits JSON doc candidate
    WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(:ids, CAST(user_id AS JSON))
    SQL;

$search = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$search->execute([':ids' => $ids]);
$users = $search->fetchAll();
```

Whe can also use `JSON_TABLE()` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) for more complex cases and JSON data exploration :

```
$users = [
    ['id' => 123, 'bday' => ..., 'address' => ...],
    ['id' => 234, 'bday' => ..., 'address' => ...],
    ['id' => 345, 'bday' => ..., 'address' => ...],
]; // I'd like to know their login

$users = json_encode($users);

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT ALL user_id, user_login
    FROM users
    WHERE user_id IN (
        SELECT ALL user_id
        FROM JSON_TABLE(:users, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            -- Data exploration...
            -- (if needed I can explore really deeply with NESTED kword)
            user_id INT PATH '$.id',
            -- I could skip these :
            user_bday DATE PATH '$.bday',
            user_address TINYTEXT PATH '$.address'
        )) AS _
    )
    SQL;

$search = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$search->execute([':users' => $users]);
...
```

Comment: with integers it works, with strings having spaces or dashes it does not

Answer (score 0):

you first set number of "?" in query  and then by a "for" send parameters
like this :

```
require 'dbConnect.php';
$db=new dbConnect();
$array=[];
array_push($array,'value1');
array_push($array,'value2');
$query="SELECT * FROM sites WHERE kind IN (";

foreach ($array as $field){
    $query.="?,";
}
$query=substr($query,0,strlen($query)-1);
$query.=")";
$tbl=$db->connection->prepare($query);
for($i=1;$i<=count($array);$i++)
    $tbl->bindParam($i,$array[$i-1],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$tbl->execute();
$row=$tbl->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
var_dump($row);
```

Answer (score -1):

I took it a bit further to get the answer closer to the original question of using placeholders to bind the params.

This answer will have to make two loops through the array to be used in the query.  But it does solve the issue of having other column placeholders for more selective queries.

```
//builds placeholders to insert in IN()
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    $in_query = $in_query . ' :val_' . $key . ', ';
}

//gets rid of trailing comma and space
$in_query = substr($in_query, 0, -2);

$stmt = $db->prepare(
    "SELECT *
     WHERE id IN($in_query)";

//pind params for your placeholders.
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    $stmt->bindParam(":val_" . $key, $array[$key])
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could convert this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN('.$in.')');
```

In this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(:id1, :id2, :id3, :id7, :id8, :id9)');
```

And execute it with this array:

```
$stmt->execute(array(
        :id1 =>1, :id2 =>2, :id3 =>3, :id7 =>7, :id8 =>8, :id9 => 9
    )
);
```

Thus:

```
$in = array();
$consultaParam = array();
foreach($ids as $k => $v){
    $in[] = ':id'.$v;
    $consultaParam[':id'.$v] = $v;
}
```

Final code:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,7,8,9);
$db = new PDO(...);

$in = array();
$consultaParam = array();
foreach($ids as $k => $v){
    $in[] = ':id'.$v;
    $consultaParam[':id'.$v] = $v;
}

$stmt = $db->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM table
     WHERE id IN('.$in.')'
);
$stmt->execute($consultaParam);
```